# How to configure i18next to lookup nested values in JSON?

Tags: javascript, i18next

I have the following `i8next` config

```
i18next.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true,
  resources: {
    en: {
      translation: {
        loadPath: '../locales/en.json'
      }
    },
    nl: {
      translation: {
        loadPath: '../locales/nl.json'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I would like to be able to load translations like

```
{
  "commands": {
    "help": {
      "description": "Some description."
    }
  }
}
```

Preferred usage would be: `t('commands.help.description')`

How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What mentioned is working out of the box. You should consider using [i18next namespacing](https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces) also.

Comment: Could you show me a simple example? with the out of the box scentence you mentioned I get `i18next::translator: missingKey nl translation commands.help.description commands.help.description` with the usage in my question, I would appreciate a minimal example using namespaces

Answer (score 0):

im not sure why you cannot do it, but i attached an example:

```
check line 28: i18next.t('help.welcome')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/orestes22/gw2x7uvd/7/

Also you can fin more info here, in the official page:

https://github.com/i18next/i18next-gitbook/blob/master/overview/getting-started.md

Also, please, check your code, your namespace is "translation", but you are using "commands", so you must write in your code like this t('help.description')

The namespace "translation" it is the default namespace, but if you want use a custom, follow this instructions:
Here there is an example of "init" with different namespace : https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces

Here you will find where it said "traslation is the default namespace": https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options

I hope i could help you
Best Regards